# Javafx: Change in-line css style during runtime

Tags: css, javafx, background, inline, maximize-window

I am attempting to change the background image of a pane when the application is maximized. My background is set using in-line css. I've set up two different variables for the styling and an if statement. However, I'm not having any luck getting it to change the styling.

```
String cssStyle = "-fx-background-image: url(\'file:images/poker_table.png\');" +
                 "-fx-background-position: center center;" +
                 "-fx-background-radius: 15;" + // ************* For rounded corners
                 "-fx-background-size: 100% 100%;";
String cssStyle2 = "-fx-background-image: url(\'file:images/poker_table.jpg\');" +
                  "-fx-background-position: center center;" +
                  "-fx-background-radius: 15;" +
                  "-fx-background-size: 100% 100%;";
if (!primaryStage.isMaximized())
{   gameScreen.setStyle(cssStyle);
}
else
{   gameScreen.setStyle(cssStyle2);
}
```

Comment: Register a listener (or bind to) the [`maximized` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#maximizedProperty)

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The same way you register a listener with any JavaFX property.

Comment: It isn't your core issue, but I'd advise placing the CSS in a CSS file that you loaded, defining each option with a separate style class, and adding and removing the style class as appropriate (in the registered listener).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a listener to the stage's `maximizedProperty()`. Properties and listeners are a fundamental part of the JavaFX API: you can read about them in the [standard documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm), or any good JavaFX tutorial.

```
primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener((obs, wasMaximized, isNowMaximized) -> {
    if (isNowMaximized) {
        gameScreen.setStyle(cssStyle2);
    } else {
        gameScreen.setStyle(cssStyle);
    }
});
```

You probably also need to set the appropriate style immediately, using the code you already have.

You can use a binding instead, if you prefer:

```
gameScreen.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
    () -> primaryStage.isMaximized() ? cssStyle2 : cssStyle,
    primaryStage.maximizedProperty()
);
```

The binding can replace the code you already have; it will both be applied immediately and any time the `maxmizedProperty` changes.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I used the listener and it worked perfectly. I'll dig into the binding to learn how that works as well. This is all new for me.

Comment: Do you know why isMaximized() didn't work? I used that to change the maximize button to a restore button.

Comment: @ajkelsey In what sense does `isMaximized()` not work? Your original code will set the style depending on the current state of `maximized` at the time the code is executed. Nothing there tells it to change the style when that property changes.